# Adding GPT HDD to MBR installed Server

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, mbr

My Server is set with 500GB HDD (MBR Formatted), Now I brought 1TB WD HDD to expand the storage. I have initialized new HDD with GPT partition. MY server is running Windows 2008 R2. Is it possible to accommodate GPT HDD with existing MBR partition one. OS and all applications are running in old disk and the new hdd is for storing more data. Please let me know whether both work together.

Comment: Only for data means there won't be any problem.

Comment: The storage limit in current hdd almost 80%, that's why I brought additional. This hdd is only to storage data and share the same with network users.

Comment: It should work as a data-only disk; however, you should be aware that a 1 TB disk is still a bit less than half of the 2TiB limit where GPT becomes necessary. Thus, you could also use the disk as an MBR disk without difficulties. It's not a big deal either way, at least in theory; but having a consistent set of partition table types across all disks will make future confusion about boot modes less likely.